# Applying Button+Macro across all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, button

Forgive my ignorance (newby and little knowledge of VBA)...

I have developed some macros that are attached to buttons, and working in one worksheet in a workbook. The macros perform various jobs on a calendar. There is one calendar for each of 10 bedrooms in the wing of a hospital.

I now want to make identical worksheets with the same buttons and macros for each bedroom i.e. 10 worksheets.

But try as I might I cant get the macros to work in the other worksheets.

The macros are in the VBA code editor for the first worksheet (Bed1). I have copied the code into the "This Workbook" page within the VBA editor - but that had no effect, other than to stop them working at all.

This is a typical macro:

```
'============================================
Private Sub Prevw1_Click()
'============================================
' DAILY PATIENT TIMETABLE
' PRINT PREVIEW
'============================================
    ActiveSheet.Select
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Range("_Daily").Select
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "_Daily"
'
    Call page_SetUp
'
' Variations for page setup
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1.5)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.9)
        .Zoom = 75
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Range("H126, H126").Select
End Sub
```

Q. What have I done wrong that makes this only work in the Bed1 worksheet where it was developed  first?

Kind regards
Russ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the code out of the `ThisWorkbook` module and put it in a normal code module.  In Design Mode, in the Excel window (not VBE), right-click the button and do `Assign Macro`, then choose the macro "Prevw1_Click".  That should work.  You'll have to assign the macro to each button, or you could simply copy/paste the button to the other sheets.

If your button is an ActiveX Control, then I think you may need to have the subroutine for each button in the worksheet where the button resides.  So, each worksheet may have an activeX command button called "CommandButton1", then each `Worksheet` code module should have a subroutine like:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call ClickTheButton
End Sub
```

You will basically put all of this same code in each of the 10 worksheet code modules.  Then, rename your routine in the ordinary code module, like:

```
Private Sub ClickTheButton()
'============================================
' DAILY PATIENT TIMETABLE
' PRINT PREVIEW
'============================================
    ActiveSheet.Select
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Range("_Daily").Select
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "_Daily"
'
    Call page_SetUp
'
' Variations for page setup
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1.5)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.9)
        .Zoom = 75
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Range("H126, H126").Select
End Sub
```

The reason I would do this, instead of copying the existing macro to each of 10 worksheets is simple: If you ever need to modify your subroutine, you only need to modify it in one place. Likewise, if you add a new worksheet(s) you need only copy 3 lines of code instead of 20.  It's just easier to maintain this way, since each sheet's button is calling the same code, each sheet's button should just have a simple sub that calls the "main" procedure.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I put the code into the Worksheet 'Bed1' VBA module. Then I copied the Worksheet 'Bed1' button to Worksheet 'Bed2'- but that did not work. Should I change the 'name' of the button in 'Properties' to 'Prevw1' ? Also, when I right click the new button there is no option to 'Assign Macro'...?

Comment: What version of excel are you using? Also do you know whether it is a Form Control or an ActiveX control?   Instructions above tested & work on form controls in Excel 2010; should also work in 2007 but may not be applicable in Excel 2003.

Comment: Hi David - I just experimented with a Form Control button and the right click does offer the "assign macro" option...so my buttins must be ActiveX type...is that a problem?

Comment: With an ActiveX control, I think you do need a subroutine in *each* worksheet module. I'll update my answer with a suggestion on how to implement with the least messy option, but this is why I generally prefer form controls or shapes with an assigned macro :)

Comment: Hi David. What a pain! I have about 20 routines in each worksheet - and you are quite right I only want to edit the code in one place. So I think I have two options. A) Do as you suggest with 20 small code fragments in each worksheet each calling the appropriate VBA. or, B) replace the 20 buttons I have with Form type buttons instead of ActiveX type...and then do the copy and paste/assign macro job. Do you concur?

Comment: I concur. I'd use regular buttons or shapes instead of activex controls.  I've never liked ActiveX controls for this reason among other reasons and while there may be some case that requires them,  I haven't encountered it yet.  Anything I've ever needed to do could be done using a normal button or shape.

Comment: Thank you David. Very good of you to take time to ponder my vain attempt to avoid a tedious programming task. But it is a shame that Excel cant have globally accessible code across a Workbook.

Comment: For activex controls it might be possible if you use a class module/with events I haven't tried it though and it seems like more trouble than its worth especially if you don't **need** to use the ActiveX style controls.  Anyways you're welcome and glad I could help!